# ScrollView Should Start from Specific Item in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, scrollview, tabbar

I have an array of **years** and a **selected year**. What I want is whenever my View loads, it should move automatically to the **selected year**.

Here is my code:

```
struct Testing: View {
    let years = ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024", "2025", "2026"]
    @State var selectedYear = "2023"
    @Namespace private var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                
                ForEach(years.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    
                    Button {
                        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.5)) {
                            selectedYear = years[index]
                        }
                    } label: {
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(years[index])")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                            
                            if selectedYear == years[index] {
                                Capsule()
                                    .fill(.white)
                                    .frame(height: 5)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, -5)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding().background {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.purple)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is returning

[image: return image]

Whenever the View loads it should show the **selectedYear** in the middle. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Embed the `ScrollView` inside a `ScrollViewReader`, add to the `Button `inside the `ForEach` loop a `.id(years[index])` modifier and lastly, add to the `ScrollView` the following modifier:

`.onAppear {
   scrollProxy.scrollTo(id: currentYear)
}`

Assuming you called the `ScrollViewReader` parameter `scrollProxy` and `currentYear` is the computed current year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ScrollViewReader` container view which gives a mechanism to read a scroll view's content offset and scroll to a particular piece of material therein with `scrollTo` method.
Here is the Updated code:

```
struct Testing: View {
    let years = ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024", "2025", "2026"]
    @State var selectedYear = "2023"
    @Namespace private var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollView in // --> Here
                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                    
                    ForEach(years.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        
                        Button {
                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.5)) {
                                selectedYear = years[index]
                            }
                        } label: {
                            VStack {
                                Text("\(years[index])")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                                
                                if selectedYear == years[index] {
                                    Capsule()
                                        .fill(.white)
                                        .frame(height: 5)
                                        .padding(.horizontal, -5)
                                }
                            }
                            .id(years[index]) // ---> Here
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding().background {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.purple)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    scrollView.scrollTo(selectedYear, anchor: .center) // ---> Here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```